# Properties on nested objects in ember doesn't fire if the object key was in PascalCase

Tags: ember.js

This is a why this happens question

like the title suggests, if I have a PascalCase object key, custom properties on it won't fire when the model properties changes

Here is an example

```
App.CustomModel = Ember.Object.extend({
  workProp: function() {
    return this.get('work.val');
  }.property('work.val'),
  wontWorkProp: function() {
    return this.get('WontWork.val');
  }.property('WontWork.val')
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return App.CustomModel.create({
      work: {
        val: 'Bar'
      },
      WontWork: {
        val: 'Bar'
      }
    });
  }
});
```

and the hbs

```
<h2>This works</h2>
<div>
  {{model.workProp}}
  {{model.work.val}}
  {{input value=model.work.val}}
</div>
<h2>This doesn't</h2>
<div>
  {{model.wontWorkProp}}
  {{model.WontWork.val}}
  {{input value=model.WontWork.val}}
</div>
```

Fiddle: http://jsbin.com/lukahogeye/2/edit?html,js,output

Any idea why?

Comment: This is how Ember works by convention. It expects camelCase for object keys, and PascalCase for namespaces and classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted the issue on the issues list in ember github. its a bug that might be fixed in the future

https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/10414